# Determine which condition is true in a boolean expression being used in if condition

Tags: javascript, c#, python

Suppose we have a simple `boolean` expression filled with boolean return type function calls with `logical OR` operators between them. This `boolean` expression is used only in a single `if` clause. For example:

```
if (c1() or c2() or c3()): #c1(), c2(), c3() are sample boolean return type methods
  foo1()
  foo2()
  print ("foo1() and foo2() have been executed because condition # <number> is true")
```

1. Is it possible to find out the method call (most basic unit of
   condition such as `c2()` is condition # 2) because of which the
   program entered the code inside the if clause without storing the
   return values of any of the method call or calling any method again?
2. Suppose `c1()`, `c2()` and `c3()` would have all returned `true`
   boolean values. However due to `short-circuit boolean evaluation`,
   `c2()` and `c3()` would never be executed. Can we somehow find it because of which conditions/method calls, the program might have still entered the code block inside the if clause while applying the same conditions mentioned in point number 1.

The answer can be in any programming language. I'm just curious to see if it is and how it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you tagged both on `python` and `c#`, the answer can be completly different in each language.

In c# I would have done it in the following pattern:

```
public ResultModel checkSomething()
{
    ResultModel retVal = new ResultModel();

    if(condition1)
    {
        retVal.DidSucceed = true;
        retVal.Source = eSource.Condition1;
    }
    else if (condiction2){
        ...
    }

    return retVal;
}

class ResultModel
{
    public bool DidSucceed {get;set;}
    public eSource Source {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: That's one approach to do so but it has multiple `if` statements. The question involves only a single `if` statement.

Comment: @tehmas that's the point, you shold not use a single statement for your needs. trust a developer with 10 years of experiance. write clean code, and not `short` code

Comment: @omirman12 Thanks for replying. However, in this question I am more interested about the tricky part rather than following `clean-code` methodology. Obviously, it can easily be achieved by having multiple `if` statements but that isn't the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this in Python,

```
condn = 0
for i, c in enumerate((c1(), c2(), c3()):
    if c:
        condn = i + 1
        break
if condn:
  foo1()
  foo2()
  print("condition number #{} is true".format(condn))

# if c2() is true, it prints
"condition number #2 is true"
```

Comment: This is quite the same as "without storing the return values of any of the method call". I'm looking for a solution in which `if (c1() or c2() or c3())` remains the same.

Comment: @tehmas I highly doubt if it's possible to do so. If you need the index of the condition, at some point, you will have to keep track of indices.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something tricky like this, but not the best solution

```
check = []
def c1():
    global check
    if True: check.append('c1')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is no, whenever one of the functions returns `true` the code inside the if will execute and you can't see what are the values without the debbuger or storing the values in some variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get this behaviour without polluting namespace with global variables or turning `c*` functions into classes I would implement it like this:

```
conditions = [c1, c2, c3]
for index, cond in enumerate(conditions):
    if cond():
        foo1()
        foo2()
        print(f"foo1() and foo2() have been executed because condition {index} is true")
        break
```

this basically hardcodes `or` behaviour, but other than that is fine.

Comment: Although this does solve the problem, I am interested in a solution which does not involve changing the `if (c1() or c2() or c3())` statement in any way.

Comment: @tehmas Well... You are requesting the information that python or C# do not expose. If you want to get it you need to modify the condition functions, so that they can remember being called. If you can allow changing `or` to `|` (bitwise or) operator, then you can get per-if info. Otherwise the solution is to just wrap conditions into some class or decorator that marks being called and later check which conditions were called (this is not bound to the particular `if`). Choose your approach, and I'll implement it. Ether way this will be a hack, at least 5x more complex than original answer.